# Mi pregunta es acerca de STContains en SQLServer 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo un problema para consultar un tabla con esta estructura:

```
create TABLE [tbl_zonas](
id   int,
area geography);

INSERT [dbo].[tbl_zonas] ([id], [area]) 
VALUES (1, 0xE610000001040500000088179F5D19B534402D6002B76EC455C0281B20E230B634402B4025F8F0C455C04B18721184B4344075221C0E26C555C00A82C7B777B33440BBD6DEA7AAC455C088179F5D19B534402D6002B76EC455C001000000020000000001000000FFFFFFFF0000000003) 
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_zonas] ([id], [area]) 
VALUES (2, 0xE6100000010405000000C319B27048A734400281CEA4CDC655C07E6DA23B2DA834409D4A06802AC755C097D17E5AFBA53440EE30DC6FA3C755C0E2D528DA0BA5344099EA138A3EC755C0C319B27048A734400281CEA4CDC655C001000000020000000001000000FFFFFFFF0000000003)
```

Dichas áreas almacenadas son polígonos. tengo problemas con un Query que necesito retornar la zona a la que pertenece un punto GPS (longitud,latutid). 
el `select` q realizo es de esta manera:

```
DECLARE @h geography;   
SET @h = geography::Parse('POINT(-121.703796 46.893985)');  

select id
from [tbl_zonas]
where area.STContains(@h)= 1;
```

siempre me retorna otro `ID` y debería retornar el id del área a la que pertenece el `@h`.

Comment: Puedes compartir datos de prueba? Que incluyan la fila correcta y la incorrecta.

Comment: Hola Luis, ejemplos:  INSERT [dbo].[tbl_zonas] ([id], [area]) VALUES (1, 0xE610000001040500000088179F5D19B534402D6002B76EC455C0281B20E230B634402B4025F8F0C455C04B18721184B4344075221C0E26C555C00A82C7B777B33440BBD6DEA7AAC455C088179F5D19B534402D6002B76EC455C001000000020000000001000000FFFFFFFF0000000003)
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_zonas] ([id], [area]) VALUES (2, 0xE6100000010405000000C319B27048A734400281CEA4CDC655C07E6DA23B2DA834409D4A06802AC755C097D17E5AFBA53440EE30DC6FA3C755C0E2D528DA0BA5344099EA138A3EC755C0C319B27048A734400281CEA4CDC655C001000000020000000001000000FFFFFFFF0000000003)

Comment: No hay datos en la tabla, sólo el de la variable.

Comment: disuclpa no se copio el insert

Comment: Los datos que compartiste son 2 polígonos que se encuentran en el rango  de -87 en el eje X. Eso está muy alejado del punto que se encuentra en el -121.

Comment: puedes seleccionar cualquier punto gps dentro de esos poligonos y no funciona.

Comment: Intenta con esto 
`SET @h = geography::Parse('POINT(-87.075 20.705)');  `

Comment: Disculpa Luis, te reenvio los datos de un poligono y un punto gps dentro del poligono, y al hacer la consulta no aparece el area al que pertenece ese punto. estoy usando la misma estructura de la tabla arriba descrita con este insert: INSERT [dbo].[tbl_zonas] ([id], [area]) 
VALUES ('1','0xE610000001040500000088179F5D19B534402D6002B76EC455C0281B20E230B634402B4025F8F0C455C04B18721184B4344075221C0E26C555C00A82C7B777B33440BBD6DEA7AAC455C088179F5D19B534402D6002B76EC455C001000000020000000001000000FFFFFFFF0000000003') y el punto dentro de este poligino es (-87.0744611, 20.7074484).

Comment: A mí sí me regresa el resultado (corrigiendo la declaración).

Comment: Que version de SQLserver tienes? y si agregas más poligonos a la tabla con distintas ubicaciones te sigue retornando el area al q corresponde el punto GPS?. el problema no es que no retorne data. el problema es -> siempre me retorna otro ID y debería retornar el id del área a la que pertenece el @h

Comment: Si agrego más polígonos me retorna todos los polígonos a los que pertenece el punto. Estoy probando en las versiones 2016 y 2012 porque son las que tengo a la mano.

Comment: Los poligonos que tengo son varios y no se interceptan. son distintos. entonces si selecciono un punto gps que pertenece a la zona a, debería solo retornarme la zona a y me retorna otras zonas. no se que estoy haciendo mal. mi version es Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12